# 403 error my first Azure role

Tags: azure, cloud

I just down loaded Azure SDK and created my firest WCF Service Role clicked on F5 but it goes to 127.0.0.1:81 and says

403 Access denied - forbidden ....

thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by Julien, please type the complete address. Otherwise IIS thinks you’re requesting the directory to list files, which by default is not allowed.

Answer (score 1):

Try 127.0.0.1:81/Service1.svc ;)

Change Service1 by the name of your project